# How can I use python in Blender Game Engine (2.5+) to save the depth buffer AND the color buffer to file every frame?

Tags: blender

I need to save the color buffer and depth buffer of a given camera in a scene in Blender Game Engine every frame to a file (each to their own file). Is this possible? How can this be setup using the BGE and python?

Ive asked on the Blender Artists forum but noone seems to have picked up the question.

Comment: I think I have a solution for you, however this question is not a good fit for stack overflow, ask again on super user, and post the link, and I will answer there.

Comment: Okay, good point. I just posted there. And I voted to close here.

Comment: For future reference the question is now on super user...http://superuser.com/questions/434385/how-can-i-use-python-in-blender-game-engine-2-5-to-save-the-depth-buffer-and/434387#434387